# Using NodeJS and MySQL, await/async functions sometimes not waiting for query to finish

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I have two async functions,

```
async function sqlPushSteamappid(appId){
    let tmp;
    let sql='INSERT INTO cleetusbot.tmp (appId) VALUES ('+appId+');';
    tmp = new Promise((res, rej) => {
        global.pool.query(sql, function (err, results, fields) {    
            if(err){
                console.log(err);
            }
        });
    });
    return await tmp;
}
```

and

```
async function sqlGetSteamNames(){
    let tmp;
    let sql='SELECT * FROM cleetusbot.steamGames INNER JOIN tmp ON cleetusbot.steamGames.appId = cleetusbot.tmp.appId;';
    tmp = new Promise((res, rej) => {
        global.pool.query(sql,function (err, results, fields) {    
            if(err){
                console.log(err);
            }
            res(results);
        });
    });
    await tmp;
    return tmp;
}
```

Both return what I need, however most of the time when they are called the MySQL queries either don't fully return completely, or don't return an answer at in within the promise. Am I missing something in my code or do I have to make the MySQL timeout longer?
Here is how im calling them in my code:

```
for(let i = 0; i < gameList.length; i++){
                sqlPushSteamappid(gameList[i]);
            }
            //sometimes does not return anything
            let steamNameObj = await sqlGetSteamNames();
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should understand why things happen the way they do in your snippet.

Don't think of your mysql at all, those asynchronous calls act like any other; also take into account that a `for` iteration is asynchronous itself which means that all the function calls inside `for` will be called without waiting for the previous to be finished (even if you `await` them). `sqlGetSteamNames()` will also be called right after all your `sqlPushSteamappid()` are called (again, without waiting for them to finish).

You need to get rid of the uncertainty of execution order and you can do that having your `sqlPushSteamappid()` return a promise, and use `Promise.all` ([docs here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)) to coordinate your requests. So first feed all your `sqlPushSteamappid()` in `Promise.all` and then after it returns, you can call `await sqlGetSteamNames()` as you do in your code.

Working example:

```
const promises = [
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => resolve("3 sec passed"), 3000);
    }),
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => resolve("2 sec passed"), 2000);
    }),
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => resolve("4 sec passed"), 4000);
    })
];

const ending = async () => { setTimeout(() => { console.log("2 sec to finish") }, 1000); }

const start = async () => {
    const results = await Promise.all(promises);
    console.log(results);
    await ending();
}

start();
```